# How to split Numeric Values and Words from a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, substring

I have a string `"10 = On Battery "`, I have to split the numeric value `10` and words `"On Battery"`(Including the space in between them) and store it in separate variables. Please help me with some example java code.

Comment: this question really lacks research effort.. Did you search SO before asking?

Comment: **Surprise....!!!** You question contains answer!!! :)

Comment: Your question lacks any effort.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After considering your `String` It made me to add one thing

```
    String s2= "10 = On Battery ";  
    String s[]=s2.split("=");
    int i=Integer.parseInt(s[0].trim());<-----------
use trim() otherwise you will have "10 " with whitespace
                                      ^
```

But......

> I have to split the numeric value 10 and words "On Battery"(**Including
>   the space in between them**)

```
String a=s2.split("=")[0];//"10 "
String b=s2.split("=")[1];//" On Battery "
```

Comment: " On Battery " is prefixed and suffixed with spaces. Can you tell me a way to remove those spaces without affected space between On and Battery.

Comment: I answered that use `trim()` it will remove extra spaces prefix and suffix as well

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
String originValue = "10 = On Battery";
String [] splitedValue = originValue.split("/s=/s");
System.out.println(splitedValue[0]); // 10
System.out.println(splitedValue[1]); // On Battery
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
String s= "10 = On Battery ";  
String split[]=s.split("=");
```

`split[0]` will have 10 and `split[1]` will have On Battery

Comment: And then you can do Integer.parseInt(split[0]) in order to get it as an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `Stirng.split`. Also It is very simple thing you try to learn String methods for like wise manipulation.